# pyspark: inconsistent results when using take() function of an RDD

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, rdd

I have noticed that if I tried to check out a few records from an RDD using:

```
myRDD.take(5)
```

I sometimes got inconsistent results. Sometimes I got 5 records, and other times it returns empty result `[]`.

I think it is probably okay as each time it might be taking 5 records from different nodes, and some nodes happen to have no data. But I would like to confirm if this guess is correct?

Also, if this is the case, how would people guarantee to get some non-empty results using `take()` method? Even the entire RDD is not empty, one might keep hitting the node without any data.

Comment: how are you testing it ? are you testing continuously ?

Comment: The `take()` function isn't deterministic, but it should still return 5 records if there are at least 5 in the rdd.